# Scheduler pattern with JAVA: how to check if current date time matches pattern

Tags: java, database, pattern-matching, scheduled-tasks

I'm wondering how to do some pattern matching in JAVA for date time. I have a database which has some entries that need to be scheduled.

Basically, I have a program that runs each 30 minutes. Inside this program (I own the code) I want to do a check against the database records on a field (non existent yet) if the current date / time matches the record's scheduler.

Examples of scheduler option should be something like:
- daily + given hour
- weekly + given hour
- monthly + given hour
- each Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday or ... at given hour

How should I store the scheduler pattern value (string, datetime, ?) and do the comparison inside my JAVA code to see if it matches?

Thanks

Comment: Leave an empty line before the list, in your post (after ..like:).   

Java provides the [`Calendar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, which has an `add(field, amount)` method. Use something that's compatible with that, I guess it'll help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 2445 should be useful to deal witch scheduling and recurrence. Here is a java library http://code.google.com/p/google-rfc-2445/.

You could store recurrence rules as a text in RRULE format, then parse it with the library to calculate the next recurrence date/time.

It should also be useful to change the app logic the other way around - to schedule execution at the specific calculated time, not to execute every 30 minutes trying to match the current time with recurrence patterns.